# How to sum events by date in R

Tags: r, date, events

I have data recorded from a rain gauge. It records events of 0.2 l/m2 and the date when they occur. After a bit of processing, my data looks like this:

```
    head(df)
                       V2 V3  V4
    1 2018-10-08 11:54:43  1 0.2
    2 2018-10-08 12:49:21  2 0.2
    3 2018-10-08 15:55:33  3 0.2
    4 2018-10-08 16:43:37  4 0.2
    5 2018-10-08 16:47:41  5 0.2
    6 2018-10-08 16:56:44  6 0.2
```

note that column V2 it's the date when the event occurred, V3 it's just the cumulative counting of events, and I added column V4 with the value of l/m2 by event.

I want to sum column V4 values in a regular date sequence, by, let's say, every hour (or every day, or any other time slot), filling with "zeros" those time slots with no events

To get something like:

```
                     date  rain
    1 2018-10-08 11:00:00   0.2
    2 2018-10-08 12:00:00   0.2
    3 2018-10-08 13:00:00   0.0
    4 2018-10-08 14:00:00   0.0
    5 2018-10-08 15:00:00   0.2
    6 2018-10-08 16:00:00   0.6
```

I did solve the problem, but in a very convoluted way (see code below). Is there a straightforward way to do it?

```
    df$date<-round.POSIXt(df$V2, units = "hour")

    library(xts)

    df.xts <- xts(df$V4,as.POSIXct(df$date))

    hourly<-period.apply(df.xts,endpoints(df$date,"hours"),sum)

    hourly<-as.data.frame(hourly)
    hourly$date<-as.POSIXct(rownames(hourly))

    ref<-  data.frame(date=seq.POSIXt(from=min(df$date),to=max(df$date),by="hour"))

    all<-merge(hourly,ref,by="date",all.y = TRUE)

    all$V1[is.na(all$V1)]<-0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tidyverse` you can do:

```
library(tidyverse) 

x <- df %>%
         group_by(date = floor_date(as.POSIXct(V2), "1 hour")) %>%
         summarize(rain = sum(V4))
```

And then fill in the hours that are missing:

```
x <- as_tibble(seq(min(x$date), max(x$date), by = "hour")) %>% 
        left_join(., x, by = c("value" = "date")) %>%
        replace_na(list(rain = 0))

#  value                rain
#  <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2018-10-08 11:00:00   0.2
#2 2018-10-08 12:00:00   0.2
#3 2018-10-08 13:00:00   0  
#4 2018-10-08 14:00:00   0 
#5 2018-10-08 15:00:00   0.2
#6 2018-10-08 16:00:00   0.6
```

#### Data:

```
df <- structure(list(V2 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("     2018-10-08 11:54:43", 
"     2018-10-08 12:49:21", "     2018-10-08 15:55:33", "     2018-10-08 16:43:37", 
"     2018-10-08 16:47:41", "     2018-10-08 16:56:44"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = 1:6, V4 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```